# Bind Combobox with Enum Description

Tags: c#, combobox, enums

I have seen through Stackoverflow that there is an easy way to populate a combobox with an Enumeration:

```
cbTipos.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(TiposTrabajo));
```

In my case I have defined some Description for my enumerations:

```
 public enum TiposTrabajo
    {                  
        [Description("Programacion Otros")] 
        ProgramacionOtros = 1,           
        Especificaciones = 2,
        [Description("Pruebas Taller")]
        PruebasTaller = 3,
        [Description("Puesta En Marcha")]
        PuestaEnMarcha = 4,
        [Description("Programación Control")]
        ProgramacionControl = 5}
```

This is working pretty well, but it shows the value, not the description
My problem is that I want to show in the combobox the description of the enumeration when it have a description or the value in the case it doesn't have value.
If it's necessary I can add a description for the values that doesn't have description.
Thx in advance.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try this:

```
cbTipos.DisplayMember = "Description";
cbTipos.ValueMember = "Value";
cbTipos.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(TiposTrabajo))
    .Cast<Enum>()
    .Select(value => new
    {
        (Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString()), typeof(DescriptionAttribute)) as DescriptionAttribute).Description,
        value
    })
    .OrderBy(item => item.value)
    .ToList();
```

In order for this to work, all the values must have a description or you'll get a NullReference Exception. Hope that helps.

Comment: This is very useful. But how do you preset the combo box to a particular item?

Comment: I had to add these 2 lines for the combo box to properly identify the 2 attributes of the Select():
   cbTipos.DisplayMember = "Description";
   cbTipos.ValueMember = "Value";

Answer (score 6):

Here is what I came up with since I needed to set the default as well.

```
public static void BindEnumToCombobox<T>(this ComboBox comboBox, T defaultSelection)
{
    var list = Enum.GetValues(typeof(T))
        .Cast<T>()
        .Select(value => new
        {
            Description = (Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString()), typeof(DescriptionAttribute)) as DescriptionAttribute)?.Description ?? value.ToString(),
            Value = value
        })
        .OrderBy(item => item.Value.ToString())
        .ToList();

    comboBox.DataSource = list;
    comboBox.DisplayMember = "Description";
    comboBox.ValueMember = "Value";

    foreach (var opts in list)
    {
        if (opts.Value.ToString() == defaultSelection.ToString())
        {
            comboBox.SelectedItem = opts;
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
cmbFileType.BindEnumToCombobox<FileType>(FileType.Table);
```

Where `cmbFileType` is the `ComboBox` and `FileType` is the `enum`.