# Using Enum Description for ComboBox

Tags: c#, enums, combobox

I've been using a variety of enums and comboboxes in a system I'm programming. I have some enums with descriptions like this:

```
public enum Week
{
    [Description("Week 01")]
    Week01,
    [Description("Week 02")]
    Week02,
    [Description("Week 03")]
    Week03,
    [Description("Week 04")]
    Week04,
    [Description("Week 05")]
    Week05
}
```

And:

```
public enum Year
{
    [Description("2000")]
    Y2000,
    [Description("2001")]
    Y2001,
    [Description("2002")]
    Y2002,
    [Description("2003")]
    Y2003,
    [Description("2004")]
    Y2004,
    [Description("2005")]
    Y2005
}
```

For the comboboxes, I've been using this simple code:

```
weekComboBox.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Week));
yearComboBox.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Year));
```

This is setting up the regular enum values as would be expected. What I would like to do is have it display the `[Description()]` attribute ("Week 01" or "2002") instead of Week01 or Y2002. I've seen a lot of varieties of ways to obtain this, but I haven't been able to get it to pull the descriptions to display in the comboboxes.

What I would like to do is have a single method set up that I can just refer to for each of the comboboxes? Would I need to set up an a method per enum set instead?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35935961/bind-combobox-with-enum-description

Answer (score 3):

```
public static class EnumList
{
    public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<T, string>> Of<T>()
    {
        return Enum.GetValues(typeof(T))
            .Cast<T>()
            .Select(p => new KeyValuePair<T, string>(
                p,                   
                (p.GetType().GetField(p.ToString())
                .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false)
                .FirstOrDefault() as DescriptionAttribute)?.Description ?? p.ToString()
                ))
                .ToList();
    }
}
```

and then:

```
weekComboBox.DisplayMember = "Value"; 
weekComboBox.ValueMember = "Key"; 
weekComboBox.DataSource = EnumList.Of<Week>();
```

Comment: I ran into a couple of issues when applying this. I'm not sure if I'm missing a namespace or something.

?.Description - Invalid expression term '.'
.Description - Syntax error, ':' expected
p.ToString() - ; expected
)) - Invalid expression term ')'

Comment: @TreyStaley the ".?" or Null-conditional operator works in c# version 6. here is more info https://csharp.today/c-6-features-null-conditional-and-and-null-coalescing-operators/